# Writing an IEnumerator with performance comparable to array foreach

Tags: c#, ienumerable, roslyn

To add `foreach` support to a custom collection, you need to implement `IEnumerable`. Arrays, however, are special in that they essentially compile into a range-based for loop, which is **much** faster than using an IEnumerable. A simple benchmark confirms that:

```
                number of elements: 20,000,000
                            byte[]:  6.860ms
       byte[] as IEnumerable<byte>: 89.444ms
CustomCollection.IEnumerator<byte>: 89.667ms
```

The benchmark:

```
private byte[] byteArray = new byte[20000000];
private CustomCollection<byte> collection = new CustomCollection<T>( 20000000 );

[Benchmark]
public void enumerateByteArray()
{
  var counter = 0;
  foreach( var item in byteArray )
     counter += item;
}

[Benchmark]
public void enumerateByteArrayAsIEnumerable()
{
  var counter = 0;
  var casted = (IEnumerable<byte>) byteArray;
  foreach( var item in casted )
     counter += item;
}

[Benchmark]
public void enumerateCollection()
{
  var counter = 0;
  foreach( var item in collection )
     counter += item;
}
```

And the implementation:

```
public class CustomCollectionEnumerator : IEnumerable<T> where T : unmanaged
{
    private CustomCollection<T> _collection;
    private int _index;
    private int _endIndex;

    public CustomCollectionEnumerator( CustomCollection<T> collection )
    {
      _collection = collection;
      _index = -1;
      _endIndex = collection.Length;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
      if ( _index < _endIndex )
      {
        _index++;
        return ( _index < _endIndex );
      }
      return false;
    }

    public T Current => _collection[ _index ];
    object IEnumerator.Current => _collection[ _index ];
    public void Reset()  { _index = -1; }
    public void Dispose() {  }
}

public class CustomCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : unmanaged
{
  private T* _ptr;

  public int Length { get; private set; }

  public T this[ int index ]
  {
    [MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
    get => *_ptr[ index ];
    [MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
    set => *_ptr[ index ] = value;
  }

  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
  {
    return new CustomCollectionEnumerator<T>( this );
  }
}
```

Because arrays get special treatment from the compiler, they leave `IEnumerable` collections in the dust. Since C# focuses heavily on type safety, I can understand why this is the case, but it still incurs an absurd amount of overhead, especially for my custom collection, which enumerates in *the exact same way* as an array would. In fact, my custom collection is faster than a byte array in a range based for loop, as it uses pointer arithmetic to skip the CLR's array range checks.

So my question is: **Is there a way to customize the behavior of a `foreach` loop such that I can achieve performance comparable to an array?** Maybe through compiler intrinsics or manually compiling a delegate with IL?

Of course, I can always just use a range based for loop instead. **I am just curious as to if there is any possible way to customize the low-level behavior of a `foreach` loop in a similar manner to how the compiler handles arrays.**

Comment: So, what kind of testcode did you prepare for your benchmark? Are you just looping the array/enumerator?

Comment: @Icepickle Yes, `foreach( var item in byteArray ){}` and `foreach( var item in customCollection){}`

Comment: And the timing is from before looping till after, not including potential creation?

Comment: What is this custom collection? How are you measuring? Are you running in release mode rather than debug? There is too much unknown here to make an answer.

Comment: The benchmarking is done with BenchmarkDotNet, which times the entire enumeration of the foreach loop (20 million elements). @DavidG I have updated the question with the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type doesn't actually need to implement `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>` to be used in a `foreach` statement. The `foreach` statement is duck-typed, meaning that the compiler first looks for public methods with the right signatures (`GetEnumerator()`, `MoveNext()` and `Current`) regardless of whether they are implementations of these interfaces, and only falls back to the interfaces if necessary.

This opens the door for some optimizations that can make a significant difference in a tight loop: `GetEnumerator()` can return a concrete type instead of `IEnumerator<T>`, which then allows the `foreach` loop to be built with non-virtual and potentially inlined calls, as well as making the enumerator a `struct` to avoid the GC overhead. Certain Framework collections such as `List<T>` also take advantage of this.

Together with a couple other optimizations, this enumerator based on your `CustomCollection` gets pretty close to a raw array loop in a microbenchmark:

```
public Enumerator GetEnumerator() => new Enumerator(this);

// Being a ref struct makes it less likely to mess up the pointer usage,
// but doesn't affect the foreach loop
// There is no technical reason why this couldn't implement IEnumerator
// as long as lifetime issues are considered
public unsafe ref struct Enumerator
{
    // Storing the pointer directly instead of the collection reference to reduce indirection
    // Assuming it's immutable for the lifetime of the enumerator
    private readonly T* _ptr;
    private uint _index;
    private readonly uint _endIndex;

    public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            // This check could be omitted at the cost of safety if consumers are
            // expected to never manually use the enumerator in an incorrect order
            if (_index >= _endIndex)
                ThrowInvalidOp();

            // Without the (int) cast Desktop x86 generates much worse code,
            // but only if _ptr is generic. Not sure why.
            return _ptr[(int)_index];
        }
    }

    internal Enumerator(CustomCollection<T> collection)
    {
        _ptr = collection._ptr;
        _index = UInt32.MaxValue;
        _endIndex = (uint)collection.Length;
    }

    // Technically this could unexpectedly reset the enumerator if someone were to
    // manually call MoveNext() countless times after it returns false for some reason
    public bool MoveNext() => unchecked(++_index) < _endIndex;

    // Pulling this out of the getter improves inlining of Current
    private static void ThrowInvalidOp() => throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Comment: Fascinating. I didn't know foreach loops behaved that way. Your implementation is only about 8 nanoseconds slower than a mananged array's foreach loop. Thank you!

Comment: It is worth noting that you do need to pin the array somehow if you use this, because unless you tell the garbage collector otherwise, it is free to move things around in memory as and when it likes.